# Capturing Bluetooth data and publishing data to a website

Tags: web, bluetooth, controller, web-publishing

Hello right now I have some environmental recordings from my AC INFINITY T6 controllers in various grow tents, but they do not have wifi functionality..

[ I am not looking to control the devices as you can when you are in Bluetooth range through your mobile phone etc. ]

What I want to do is simply capture the Bluetooth data every two minutes from said T6 controllers and post to my website.

So on the go I'm not worried and can just see how the different tents are doing.

---

Now since that's proprietary hard/soft ware am I kicking a dead horse?.

Or should I just flex some of my skills and try to build a Arduino hygrometer and thermometer etc circuit for each tent and build a matrix of these Bluetooth devices that just output to my website.

If I overlooked any previous thread please post.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: A first step would be to scan for the devices using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool (e.g. [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)). If you can find the UUIDs used for the BLE characteristics then that would be helpful. They might be standard 16-bit UUID characteristics that are [documented](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf) on the Bluetooth SIG website. If they are custom characteristics then it will be a little harder work

Comment: Thanks, Lots to look through that data, on the documented site you left me thankyou, maybe I can try to build a webscraper to look for that data first!, but thanks ill dig deeper.